# How to combine multiple Excel files using Python while preserving format (fonts, etc.)

Tags: python, excel

I have a code that uses pandas that combines any given number of Excel files using pd.Dataframe while preserving the order of sheets into just one large Excel file.

However, I need to now make sure all the formatting stays the same. Fonts need to stay the same, as well as how the cells are formatted as well (if one is extended but another isn't), among other things. Is there a way to do this in Python?

Essentially, I want to "copy-paste" multiple workbooks together, not just the data within it.

```
for x in range(0, len(xlsx_filepaths)):
    #read the xl file as a file
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(xlsx_filepaths[x])
    sheetNames = xls.sheet_names
    #inputdata
    print(xlsx_filepaths[x], len(sheetNames))
    for i in range(0, len(sheetNames)):
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(xlsx_filepaths[x], sheet_name = sheetNames[i]))
        df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sheetNames[i] , index = False)
```

Comment: please add your code here.